# aggregate clickstream data in hive SQL (first value in group) CTE SQL

Tags: sql, apache, hadoop, hive

I'm analyzing website data from different websites in Apache Hive SQL and I would like to find out which domain is involved in the customer journey.
The clickstream data had the following structure:

```
id1 domain
--- ---
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    3
1    1
1    2
3    4
3    5
3    5
6    7
6    6
6    7
```

To analyze the data in the right way, I would like to transform the data into this structure:

```
id1 domain
--- ---
1    1
1    3
1    1
1    2
3    4
3    5
6    7
6    6
6    7
```

How could this be done in HIVE Sql?

I have to find out which touchpoint is involed in which sequence/order and get rid of the redundant clicks between the domains.
Ultimatly this hole query should lead to a table like this:

```
1: 1>3>1>2
3: 4>5
6: 7>6>7
```

I wouldn't say it's an hive specific question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id
       ,domain
       ,LAG(domain) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS lag_domain
FROM t_domain
) t1
WHERE lag_domain NOT LIKE domain
```

Answer (score 1):

in sql we can do using cte for hive i think we have to change varchar(100) to string i doubt corelated sub query works or not in hive.

```
;WITH list (id1 , domain, [level], list)
     AS (
    SELECT id1, domain, 1, CAST(domain AS varchar(100)) AS list
    FROM Hivetable
    WHERE domain IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT list.id1, conn.domain, list.[level]+1,
          CAST(list+' <- '+CAST(conn.domain AS varchar(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS list
    FROM list
    INNER JOIN Hivetable AS conn ON list.domain=conn.id1
    WHERE conn.domain IS NOT NULL)

SELECT id1, list AS blockedByChain
FROM list
WHERE [level]=(SELECT MAX(sub.[level]) FROM list AS sub WHERE sub.id1=list.id1)
ORDER BY id1, [level], domain;
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser ...it seem hive dosen't support correlated subqueries. Is there another way around it?

Comment: I would like to fin out more about the problem itself. How would you name the problem of the aggregation? Thanks